# Problems with wifi connection

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot

I have a netgear router wnr2200 and sometimes, when I connect with my tablet android or my cellphone, there are some problems. Using chrome, sometimes the page can load and load, I have to reload it. Using YouTube or play store, sometime it keeps on loading I have to restart (also seen with Astro file manager and freely). so I assume it is because some requests aren't succeeded.here are my home channels (my WiFi network is colored)

[image]i

I already tried channel8 and 1, no success. Any idea (channel 14 is not supported)

Comment: Is switching to the 5 GHz band an option? I just checked here, and have the entire band to me alone – while everybody else and his little sister is occupying all channels on 2.4 GHz :) Unfortunately, not all devices support it.

Comment: I've got the 5Ghz network for my self as well. And that's just great to have it like that

Comment: From http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/wnr2200.aspx#tab-techspecs, it isn't possible :(